# Extracting number from column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Job` with a column `Comment` containing the following data:

```
-#AB1 #XY: https://xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxx/12345/xxxxxxx
-#XY: https://xxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxx/23456/xxxxx #AB2
-#XY: https://xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxx/34567/xxxx
-#XY: https://xxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/45677/xxxxxxxx
```

So if there in #XY in the comment column it should give me the number in the link (`https://xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxx/12345/xxxxxxx`).

If there is both #XY and #AB in the column it should give me a number near #AB.

I used:

```
SELECT substring(comment FROM '[0-9]+') AS original_id,
FROM job
WHERE internal_comment LIKE '%AB%'
```

But this is giving me only first number present in the column. Can someone help me with this query.

Comment: You will want to remove the WHERE clause because you don't want to filter the rows out. You could create a CASE statement which then does the logic of IF #XY then find index or whatever and strip out the numbers ELSE IF #XY and #AB then find the #AB section in the string and get the character after that which can be substring at index.

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming there is no other digits in the link except those highlighted:

```
SELECT 
/* match in any order */
CASE WHEN comment ~ '(#AB.*#XY)|(#XY.*#AB)'
/* match #AB{ any digits } and get only the number */
THEN (REGEXP_MATCHES(Comment, '(#AB)(\d+)'))[2]
/* find the digits in the link */
ELSE (REGEXP_MATCHES(comment, '\d+'))[1] END AS original_id
FROM job;
```

Working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d8eb33075ff8f7b3866f680861dc68b3)